# How to date in the datpicker using selenium where calender defaults to Year selection first?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

[Click 1 on Date Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQrVx.png)

[Click 2 after Year Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ4G4.png)

[Click 3 after month selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d8HM.png)

I need to select date from a DatePicker. The datepicker user behavior is as below :
1. Click on the Date field.
2. It asks user to select the year. 
3. On year selection, it asks user to select month.
4. Om month selection it asks user to select the date in calender view.

I have tried to use below approaches :
Approach 1 : Trying to enter value as SendKeys without delimiter and then pressing Tab key using KEYS.Tab

```
WebElement dob = driver.findElement(DOB);
Actions Action3 = new Actions(driver);
Action3.moveToElement(dob).click().perform();
dob.sendKeys("01052001");
dob.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Approach 2 : Trying to Click on date field, then on Year, then on Month and finally on the date. Below is the Code for that :

```
driver.findElement(Year).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(Month).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(Date).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Do let me know how to handle such DatePicker and select the date from it.

Comment: do you have similar datepicker as in [here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), or can you attach screen shot of date picker and html code snip of it

Comment: No it is not similar to the above one. I have attached the screenshots here for better understanding.

Comment: after inputing date is date changes to what is inputed?

Comment: No it does not take the input values.

Answer (score 0):

you can enter the value directly to the input, usually need the slash `/` delimiter

```
WebElement dob = driver.findElement(DOB);
dob.sendKeys("01/05/2001");
```

or using datepicker API `setDate` and `JavascriptExecutor`

```
(JavascriptExecutor) driver.executeScript("$('#datepicker_id_or_class').datepicker('setDate', '01/05/2001')");
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried with the first approach but it didn't worked. The field doesn't take any inputs.

Comment: it could be not built-in jQuery datepicker, I think you have to create demo page or post the URL in the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Not 200% Sure if this is the best approach but using WebElements provided me the workaround to get the date. Below is the code snippet I used :

```
//This will select Year first
WebElement year = driver.findElement(Year);
Actions Action4 = new Actions(driver);
Action4.moveToElement(year).click().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
//This will select the month
WebElement month = driver.findElement(Month);
Actions Action5 = new Actions(driver);
Action5.moveToElement(month).click().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
//This will select the Date
WebElement anydate = driver.findElement(Date);
Actions Action6 = new Actions(driver);
Action6.moveToElement(anydate).click().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

If anyone else knows a structural way of handling this please share it with us.